# choose separator for auto column names in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

How can I choose a different separate than underscore when I use the summarise_if function and pass a list of functions?  I want my column names to only contain periods and not underscores to follow the Google Style Guide for R.

This is what I am using to create the columns:

```
wthmon %<>% summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(min, max, mean, median), na.rm = TRUE)
```

My columns end up looking like this:

```
> names(wthmon)
[1] "exp"               "stat.id"           "year"              "month"            
[5] "temp_min"          "dew_min"           "humid_min"         
"solar_min"        
[9] "rain_min"          "wind.spd_min"      "wind.dir_min"      
"wind.gust_min"    
[13] "soil.temp_min"     "soil.moist_min"    "temp_max"          "dew_max"
```

But I would rather temp.min or soil.moist.min to be consistent with my style.

Comment: especially since you've tagged this with 'tidyverse', reconsider underscores, which are endorsed in the [tidyverse style guide](http://style.tidyverse.org/syntax.html#object-names).  To me, it seems very few people are developing new code with periods in the names.

Comment: Not sure, but you can can always add `%>% setNames(gsub('_', '.', names(.)))` on the end

Comment: I will take the recommendation and follow the tidyverse style guide.

Answer (score 0):

Using `rename_all` and `gsub`:

```
iris %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(min, max, mean, median), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  rename_all(. %>% gsub("_", ".", .)) %>%
  colnames()
```

Output:

```
 [1] "Sepal.Length.min"    "Sepal.Width.min"     "Petal.Length.min"    "Petal.Width.min"    
 [5] "Sepal.Length.max"    "Sepal.Width.max"     "Petal.Length.max"    "Petal.Width.max"    
 [9] "Sepal.Length.mean"   "Sepal.Width.mean"    "Petal.Length.mean"   "Petal.Width.mean"   
[13] "Sepal.Length.median" "Sepal.Width.median"  "Petal.Length.median" "Petal.Width.median"
```

Answer (score 0):

**2020 Update**

With summarise() and across() in dplyr 1.0.0 you can now specify the .names argument

```
  iris %>%
  summarise(across(
    where(is.numeric),
    list(min = min, max = max, mean = mean, median = median),
    na.rm = TRUE,
    .names = "{.col}.{.fn}"
  ))
```