# summarize_each but use other characters as separator

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

summarize_each automatically uses "_" as a separator for the variable name to tag on the function used. Is there any way to use other characters?

I have gone here:
[choose separator for auto column names in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512446/choose-separator-for-auto-column-names-in-dplyr)

But the issue is that I already have column names that are using "_" and I eventually want to separate out the "_" that is attached after I use summarize_each, without separating my actual column name that already has "_".

This just seems like a convenience that has turned inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `dplyr::summarise_each` is deprecated in favour of `dplyr::across` which has the benefit that it provides a `.names` argument to specify the names for new columns using `glue` syntax.

Switching to `across` you could therefore achieve your desired result like shown below, where I used `mtcars` as example data and a `.` as the seperator:

```r
library(dplyr)

summarise(mtcars, across(everything(), 
                                .fns = list(mean = mean), 
                                .names = "{.col}.{.fn}"))
#>   mpg.mean cyl.mean disp.mean  hp.mean drat.mean wt.mean qsec.mean vs.mean
#> 1 20.09062   6.1875  230.7219 146.6875  3.596563 3.21725  17.84875  0.4375
#>   am.mean gear.mean carb.mean
#> 1 0.40625    3.6875    2.8125
```